# Why does AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry or IsCorsEnabled not allow CORS with a custom scheme handler?

Tags: c#, angular, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

**Context**

We are using [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) (v57.0) hosting an Angular2 (v4.2) application that is using shared components between a web application and game UI client. It is intended that the game client makes requests to the server from within the CEFSharp container.

The client game application is loaded within a single `index.html` loaded from an embedded resource. This is based off this [Create A Desktop Application using Angular, Bootstrap and C#](https://blog.dmbcllc.com/create-a-desktop-application-using-angular-bootstrap-and-c/) article.

**Problem**

When I make a request to the server the CEF game client logs the following error:

> http://localhost:53462/Some/Api/Method. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://embedded' is therefore not allowed access.

After CEF initialises I call `Cef.AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry("http://embedded", "http", "localhost:53462", true);` which returns **true** indicating it should be allowed. Why is it not white-listing the domain?

**Code**

Stripped down resource handler:

```
public class EmbeddedResourceHandlerFactory : ISchemeHandlerFactory
{
    private Assembly assembly = null;

    public EmbeddedResourceHandlerFactory(Assembly assembly)
    {
        this.assembly = assembly;
    }

    public IResourceHandler Create(IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string schemeName, IRequest request)
    {
        // Calculate the resource being loaded
        Uri uri = new Uri(request.Url);
        string path = uri.PathAndQuery + uri.Fragment;

        // Calculate the final path of the embedded resource
        string mime = ResourceHandler.GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension(path));
        path = $"{assembly.GetName().Name}.Views{path}".Replace("/", ".");
        if (!assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Any(x => x.Equals(path)))
            return null;

        // Create the resource handler
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(path);
        return ResourceHandler.FromStream(stream, mime);
    }
}
```

Here is how it is registered

```
settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme()
{
    SchemeName = "http",
    DomainName = "embedded",
    SchemeHandlerFactory = new EmbeddedResourceHandlerFactory(assembly),
    IsCorsEnabled = true,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. It was nothing to do with `CEFSharp` or `Angular`. The error was misleading and the issue was the server was not setup to allow CORS. In my case, the server application is `Asp.Net Core` and easy to enable for my `http://embedded` custom scheme handler:

**1**: Add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` nuget package to the server application.

**2**: Add the Cors service to the ConfigureServices method of `Startup.cs`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}
```

**3**: Tell the Configure method of `Startup.cs` to use Cors

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins("http://embedded").AllowAnyMethod());
}
```